# Adding the Values of a Column which is in a DataTable in Memory

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datatable, addition

I have a DataTable with columns Amount (Decimal), Bank(String) and AccountNo(string).
this table is stored in the memory in run time, so i want to add the amount of all rows in the table and store it to a variable

for eg: amount contains values  1000,5000,7000,6000 then i want to add all this values and store the answer in a variable

any help appreciated,
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which C# version? (because there is Linq-to-Datasets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use[`Enumerable.Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx):

```
decimal totalAmount = table.AsEnumerable().Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("Amount"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a datacolumn for the property using Expression property. 
Learn more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
DataColumn c = new DataColumn();
c.Expression = "Sum(Amount)";
```

and use it in a variable.

Advantages of using expressions is that you will not need to evaluate sum every time you add a row.

or u can run a linq query on the rows and find the sum as:

```
dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(t=> Convert.ToInt32(t["Amount"])).Sum();
```

There are many ways to write linq you can learn about linq statements [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397933.aspx) & [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397947.aspx).